# Roaming Outlook Settings without using roaming profiles

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook, roaming-profile

Is there a way to roam my Outlook 2013 settings from workstation to workstation without using Active Directory roaming profiles? As you can see from my question I am no Exchange expert...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for Exchange server settings, contacts, mail to follow you. Are you are talking about personal dictionary, client side only rules, etc.?

Are you using Outlook 2013 with on premise Exchange, Office 365, etc.?